# Tournaments of order 7 are there that are not strongly connected?

Tags: graph-theory

How many tournaments of order 7 are there that are not strongly connected? Also, how many tournaments of order 7 exist? I know there are 56 tournaments of order 6, 12 of order 5, and 4 of order 4, but I am confused as to how this is determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at some of the links from [sequence A000568](http://oeis.org/A000568) in the OEIS to learn about the general methods; the formula on that page comes from applying Burnside's lemma ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)) to reduce it to a problem about counting *labeled* tournaments that are left unchanged by some given permutation of the vertex set. But this requires some group theory to implement.

For very small $n$, it's easier to approach the problem by a structural observation about tournaments: we can divide the vertex set of any tournament into blocks $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_k$ such that each $B_i$ induces a strongly connected tournament while the edges between the blocks are completely acyclic: if $v \in B_i$ and $w \in B_j$ and $i>j$, then the edge between $v$ and $w$ is oriented $v \to w$.

This is still tedious for $n=7$, but in your case, if you can assume that there are $56$ tournaments of order $6$, $12$ tournaments of order $5$, $4$ tournaments of order $4$, and $2$ tournaments of order $3$, there's a simple argument by inclusion-exclusion.

All tournaments of order $7$ that are not strongly connected must fall into one of four types (with some overlap):

1. Tournaments where the first block has $|B_1| = 1$.
2. Tournaments where the first block has $|B_1| = 3$.
3. Tournaments where the last block has $|B_k| = 1$.
4. Tournaments where the last block has $|B_k| = 3$.

This is because we can't have a block of size $2$ (there are no strongly connected tournaments on $2$ vertices), and we must have at least two blocks if the tournament is not strongly connected, so at most one block can have size $>3$.

These are easy to individually count. There are $56$ tournaments of type 1: removing the first block gives a tournament on $6$ vertices. There are $4$ tournaments of type 2: the first block can only be a cycle on $3$ vertices, and removing it gives a tournament on $4$ vertices. Similarly, there are $56$ tournaments of type 3, and $4$ tournaments of type $4$.

But there is some overlap. There are $12$ tournaments that are both type 1 and type 3: removing the first and last block leaves a $5$-vertex tournament. By the same argument, there are $2$ tournaments that are type 1 and 4, $2$ tournaments that are type 2 and 3, and $1$ tournament that is type 2 and 4.

So the final answer is
$$(56 + 4 + 56 + 4) - (12 + 2 + 2 + 1) = 120 - 17 = 103.$$